# android httpClient gives me a syntax error in 2.1 but not in 2.2

Tags: android, httpclient

My app was in 2.2 but I want it to be in 2.1. I made the target change and I get an error here:

```
import android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient;
```

because I read it is supported only in 2.2 and above. So I made the following replacement:

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
```

But I get a syntax error here:

```
httpclient.close(); ## error states add cast
```

Whole code is here:

```
public static HttpClient httpclient = null;
try {
            URL aURL = new URL(url);
            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FlushedInputStream(is));
            bis.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (httpclient != null) {
                httpclient.close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that maybe because `Httpclient` doesn't have the method `close(),`
however I suggest you use the [DefaultHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html)  , here is a hint:

```
DefaultHttpClient mHttpClient = null;
```

and whenever you want to close it just call it this way:

```
mHttpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

Comment: and I leave the rest as it is?

Comment: yes, from the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/conn/ClientConnectionManager.html#shutdown%28%29 
*Shuts down this connection manager and releases allocated resources. This includes closing all connections, whether they are currently used or not.*

Answer (score 0):

`HttpClient` is an interface which doesn't define `close()` method: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html

Comment: Is it a problem if I do not close it at all?  Would you suggest something different but having the same functionality?